# Windows Phone 8 - Small Cycle Template Live Tile (159x159)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-tile

I am trying to add a small cycle template live tiles to an app.

In the documentation: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_WhatyoucandowithTiles and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207036(v=vs.105).aspx

There seems to be no samples using small cycle tiles. Also, here is a screenshot of VS2012 `WMAppManifest.xml`. There is only one image for "Small".

[image: WMAppManifest.xml screenshot]

Is it possible to add a cycle template live tile for a small image? One of the clients wants to create a "small live tile" when the application is first installed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cycle through images on a small tile, you can only have a static image. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.cycletiledata.cycleimages%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), the `CycleTileData.CycleImages` property is for medium and wide tiles.

> [CycleTileData.CycleImages] Gets or sets a collection of up to 9 background images for the medium
>   and wide Tile sizes.